# Como decodificar um objeto via URL?

Tags: java

Eu tenho a URL do objeto e precisava codificar e depois deserealizar, como faço isso? A URL é de um servidor que exibe um objeto em Java codificado e serializado.

Comment: Daniel, edite a pergunta com mais informações, essa URL retorna um JSONObject?, sua pergunta vai acabar sendo fechada.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez isso te ajude. Esse código abre uma conexão HTTP e faz o download do conteúdo. Depois disso, você só deverá decodificar o resultado. Se isso não servir, por favor explique melhor o que você está tentando fazer.

```
package testes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection c1 = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://grepcode.com").openConnection();
        int code1 = c1.getResponseCode();
        InputStream resposta = code1 >= 400 ? c1.getErrorStream() : c1.getInputStream();

        System.out.println(code1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10240);
        int r;
        while ((r = resposta.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) r);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: cara vou tentar, mas mesmo se não funcionar eu adapto ao meu código porque era exatamente isso que eu queria.